# Facebook login UIView loads weirdly whilst UI behaves as expected

Tags: ios, uiview, firebase, facebook-login

I am to going to explain this to the bed of my ability, I am still relatively new to stackoverflow.

The user interface loads as expected but the "log in with Facebook" button appears on the top right of the screen and a blue box vertically beneath the email and password fields of the login screen. 
How can I fix this without breaking my current constraints or will I have set up new constraints?

[image: The blue box of doom!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag UIButton from Object Library into your controller's xib, add the respective constraints to that button (Leading, Trailing, Vertical Spacing w.r.t. password field).

> Then change the button class to FBLoginButton from attribute inspector
>   of that button.

[image]

> take the outlet of the respective button and perform the operation.

Comment: Nice, but I still have the other button appearing in the top right though?
How can I get rid of that?

Comment: have you added it programatically?

Comment: yeah I did fixed it! Cheers!